# SQL query to calculate running counter based on previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table with vDateTime, Category column.
I want to a colum with incremental count based on previous Category value. i.e if current Category is same as previous counter will increment else it will reset to 1.
I am using `DENSE_RANK()` but how do I reset value if previous value is not same as current?

```
SELECT vDateTime, Category,
DENSE_RANK()over(Partition by Category  order by vDateTime, Category) as Rank
FROM tblA 
ORDER BY vDateTime, Category
```

[image]

Comment: Please, post sample data as text.

Comment: 4/27/2010 16:12 KCLK 1
6/15/2010 17:40 KCLE 1
7/12/2010 10:29 KCLK 2
8/13/2010 10:41 KCLK 3
8/13/2010 11:33 KCLE 2
8/17/2010 15:37 KCLE 3
9/1/2010 11:10 KCLE 4
9/17/2010 10:37 KCLE 5
9/21/2010 12:22 KCLE 6
9/27/2010 15:38 KCLE 7
9/28/2010 14:11 KXAMC 1
10/8/2010 11:18 KCLK 4
10/8/2010 15:45 KCLE 8

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would suggest the difference of row numbers:

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by category, (seqnum_2 - seqnum) order by vDateTime) as expected_output
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by vDateTime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by vDateTime) as seqnum_2,
      from tbla 
     ) a
order by vDateTime, Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with another possible approach using window functions `LAG()` and `SUM()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   vDateTime datetime, 
   Category varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (vDateTime, Category)
VALUES   
   ('2010-04-27T16:12:00', 'KCLK'), 
   ('2010-06-15T17:40:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-07-12T10:29:00', 'KCLK'), 
   ('2010-08-13T10:41:00', 'KCLK'), 
   ('2010-08-13T11:33:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-08-17T15:37:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-09-01T11:10:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-09-17T10:37:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-09-21T12:22:00', 'KCLE'),
   ('2010-09-27T15:38:00', 'KCLE'), 
   ('2010-09-28T14:11:00', 'KXAMC'), 
   ('2010-10-08T11:18:00', 'KCLK'), 
   ('2010-10-08T15:45:00', 'KCLE')
```

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (   
   SELECT 
      vDateTime, category, 
      CASE WHEN LAG(Category) OVER (ORDER BY vDateTime) = Category THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Change]
   FROM Data   
), GroupsCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      vDateTime, category, 
      SUM([Change]) OVER (ORDER BY vDateTime) AS [Group]
   FROM ChangesCTE
)   
SELECT 
   vDateTime, category, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY vDateTime) AS rn
FROM GroupsCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `lag()` analytic function once, and `sum() over ()` analytic function twice as

```
with tblB as
(
select Category, vDateTime, 
       lag(Category) over (order by vDateTime) as lg
  from tblA
), tblC as
(
select Category, vDateTime,
       case 
       when category != lg then 
         1
       else
         sum(case when category = lg then 0 else 1 end) over ( order by vDateTime )
       end as Rank   
  from tblB
)
select Category, vDateTime, 
       sum(case when rank = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over 
          ( partition by rank order by vDateTime ) + 1 as Rank 
  from tblC
 order by vDateTime
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e3dff06eada806ba9b3fa08da109d403)</kbd>